# Build vue project through vue-cli-service build while missing . in file path

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack

My vue project is completed.
When I run script 'npm run build',which is 'vue-cli-service build', I can get a pack of output files.
However in index.html file, all js and css files' path are not right.
for example:

```
<script src=js/chunk-vendors.40fba41b.js>
```

Correct one should be:

```
<script src="./js/chunk-vendors.40fba41b.js">
```

I googled a lot. Some said to modify webpack's config, which I found out impossible since vue-cli3 does not provide such config file. Some said it can be done by adding baseurl in vue.config.js file like this:

```
module.exports = {
    baseUrl: "./",
}
```

When I set baseUrl as './', the problem remains.
When I change baseUrl to "somecode/", the output files would be:

```
<script src=somecode/js/chunk-vendors.40fba41b.js>
```

I am really confused by it.
Why and how to fix this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you use `history.pushState` or build a multi page app with the `page` option because relative `baseUrl` has some limitation. cf: https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#baseurl

Comment: @Jérôme  I only use vue-router’s push function. Neither do I use html5’s pushstate nor page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

set baseurl as "././"

full vue.config.js file:

```
module.exports = {
    baseUrl: "././",
}
```

reference: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/2595#issuecomment-424570482

Comment: Note that (since Vue CLI3.3), `baseUrl` has been [deprecated](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#baseurl) in favor of `publicPath`.